# use a gerund or noun form of a word?

Tags: gerunds

I came across a question in ACT English:

> Despite a growing recognition of this ecological threat, ____ for seafood continues to rise.

Using demand or demanding?
Why demanding is not right? I can not use gerund here?

Comment: "Demand" is correct. There is no established use of the gerundial noun "demanding".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not sure if this is the best explanation but I’m gonna break down the part of the sentence after the comma since everything before the comma isn’t important grammatically and just serves as context.

---

“For seafood” is grammatically useless, it only serves the purpose of context, therefore it will be excluded in the sentences below

“Continues to rise” describes the blank word.

Now say the sentence with “demand”, then say it with demanding.

“Demand continues to rise”

“Demanding continues to rise.”

If that doesn’t help, maybe thinking about the meaning of each word can help. Demand is a word with more than one meaning.

Demand in the context of this sentence is economic, it is a noun that designates consumer preference. When there is demand for something people want it. High demand means a lot of people want it. Low demand means not many people want it.

Demanding also has multiple definitions, but it is different. Demanding can be used as an adjective or verb. When used as an adjective there are two different ways to use it.

First, it can be used to describe actions that require a lot of skill or effort. Here are two examples that might help:

1. Doctors have a **demanding** job.
2. A 10 hour trek is physically **demanding**.

Second, it can be used to describe a person who has high standards. Here is an example:

My boss wants me to be the closer every night. He is so **demanding**.

As a verb, demanding means to strongly insist or ask something. Demand can also be used as a verb in the same way. Here are some examples:

The officer is **demanding** I get out of the car.

I **demand** a refund, this product is defective.

I know this is a lot and this isn’t even everything with the word demand. But I wanted to show the difference between demand as an economic term and demand in other contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Demand more suits here. Demand itself is a noun too, so no need of making it a gerund